# How to change quarter to year in PowerBI powerquery?

Tags: date, powerbi, data-visualization, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset in which date value shows In quarter and values show as 2008Q1, 2008Q2, 2008Q3 and Power BI detect this column as a text and every time I tried to change its type to date the whole column shows Error keyword.

[image]

I want to create a new measure where I can convert quarter to year and then take the quarter average value as my calculation.
2008Q1,2008Q2 , 2008Q3,2008Q4 TO 2008.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need convert to date? Date needs to have also month and days. Isn't enough to extract year as a text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep your current column as it is now. To achieve Year and Quarter from value for other purposes, Just create 2 new column Year and Quarter using values from your existing column. Follow these below steps in **Power Query Editor**-

**Step-1:** Duplicate your Quarter column.

**Step-2:** Split the new column with fixed length either with Left 4 character or Right 2 character. Now you have 2 new column first having Year and second one having New_Quarter value in the data set.

Now rename your 2 new column with related label and use where it is required.